# PostgreSQL Error [42804]: operator class "_bpchar_ops" does not accept data type character

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I am trying to create a gin index for a character column having length 1. (it's just a simple Y/N column). If I run this SQL:

```
create index INDEX_NAME on schema.table_name using gin(field_name);
```

I get this error:

> SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: data type character has no default operator class for access method "gin"
>    Hint: You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.

If I set the operator class explicitly, like this

```
create index INDEX_NAME on schema.table_name using gin(field_name _bpchar_ops);
```

I get this error:

> SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: operator class "_bpchar_ops" does not accept data type character

Note:

I have already run this SQL to create the gin extension

```
 create extension btree_gin;
```

Comment: What's the actual data type of the field? Show `\d tablename`. At a guess, it is of type `"char"`, which is a bit of a special-case internal type and not the same thing as `char` (no quotes) or `character`, which are the SQL-standard variable-length blank-padded character data type.

Comment: So, multiple things: Types, whose name starts with `_` are (usually) the internal name of array types (f.ex. `text[]`'s internal name is `_text`). For either `char` or `"char"` you shouldn't use an array type's operator class. -- For a Y/N field, use the `boolean` type instead. It is designed to handle such data. -- Usually an index does not worth much on a `boolean` (or `boolean`-like field: columns with such few distinct values). You could, however, use [partial index(es)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) instead.

Comment: @CraigRinger It's a "CHARACTER" type with length 1

Comment: ... see available operator classes (and their respective types) for: [GIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html), [GiST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gist-builtin-opclasses.html), [SP-GiST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spgist-builtin-opclasses.html)

Comment: @pozs From your suggested link for GIN, I get class _bpchar_ops for character data types. (FYI, I cannot modify the data_type to boolean or anything else for now).

Comment: @TᴀʀᴇǫMᴀʜᴍᴏᴏᴅ no, `_bpchar_ops` is for the `character[]` type, not for the `character` type. `character[]` represents an **array** of `character` values. -- why do you want to use `gin` anyway? It does not add any value for a single-column index over (the default) `btree`.

Comment: @pozs Good point, `_bpchar` is "array of blank padded character" (the underscore is convention for "array of" for internal type names)

Comment: @pozs, so what would be the best index for single character fields?

Comment: @TᴀʀᴇǫMᴀʜᴍᴏᴏᴅ if it would be truly a single character field, then (the default) `btree`, as I mentioned. But (as I mentioned this one too) because it have such a few distinct values in your case (only Y or N) it probably never going to be used. You could try to use partial index(es) instead.

Comment: @pozs Following this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33102872/5645769 post, I am trying BRIN index. Do you think it will a good idea to use BRIN index for my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

There is no GIN operator class for `character`, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gin.html).

Since the length is 1, you could use the type `"char"` instead:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (field_name "char");
CREATE INDEX ON table_name USING gin (field_name char_ops);
```

But what whould be the use of such an index?

Comment: OP's use case is rather a `boolean`. But yes, the `btree_gin` module does define one for the `"char"` type, but it's rather useless in a single-column index.

Comment: @pozs What do you suggest for my case?

Comment: @TᴀʀᴇǫMᴀʜᴍᴏᴏᴅ I've already suggested partial indexes 2 times. But this depends on your actual problem OFC, which you want to solve with a gin index.

Comment: @pozs Sorry I missed your last comment in my post.

Comment: @Laurenz Allbe I see the same error for "char" type

Comment: Then you don't have `btree_gin` installed. Could you copy and paste your commands and the error message?